# Doing something in the background and notify user when it's done

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using nodejs has my server and React in the frontend.

There is a menu item on the UI that says View PDF, what I need to do is to get some PDF files from my S3 bucket when users choose this menu item, put some headers etc.

I can easily put a modal screen to show users the PDF files are being generated and display a link to the PDF when it's ready.

But what technology should I use if I want to do away the modal screen, but to allow users to continue to do some other stuffs and display a say dismissable alerts with the link to the PDF when it's ready.

How difficult is that and what do I need?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a simple promise -- Make the request through AJAX (or similar), and then resolve the promise once the PDF is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely take a look at [socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Web sockets allow you to establish two way communication between the client and server. For your use case, this means you can send a notification to the the client from the server.

This is not too difficult to implement but will require a bit of work on both the client and the server. You can find a lot of React examples [here](https://react.rocks/tag/WebSockets).